# Trying to join json column with other table normal column Error

Tags: php, mysql, json, join

I have two tables in Database **Product** and **Purchase**. In the **Purchase** table there is a **json_type** column, where I put all purchase data in Json format like - **Product Name, Product Id, Qnt, Price** etc. Now I'm trying to display Product **Stock**, if **Purchase** table **Product Id** same with **Product** table **ID** it should display total kg/qnt. Exp -

> Id - Name - Kg's
>
> 1 - ABC - 20
>
> 1 - ABC - 100
>
> **Total - 120**

but I'm getting error -

**FUNCTION purchase.JSON_ARRAY does not exist
SELECT `products`.*, purchase.JSON_ARRAY("total_kg") as kgs FROM `products` JOIN `purchase` ON purchase.JSON_ARRAY("product_id") = products.id**

Here is my Query Code -

```
$this->db->select('products.*, purchase.JSON_ARRAY("total_kg") as kgs');
$this->db->from('products');
$this->db->join('purchase', 'purchase.JSON_ARRAY("product_id") = products.id');

$getQuery = $this->db->get();
if($getQuery){
  return $getQuery->result_array();
}
else{
  return false;
}
```

Here is the json_type column -

```
{"products":["Asulak Silver 7"],"product_id":["4"],"qnt":["20"],"unit_price":["20"],"pack_size":["20"],"unit_pack":["1"],"packing":["Pot"],"total_kg":["20"],"total_price":["400"]}

{"products":["Asulak Silver 7"],"product_id":["4"],"qnt":["15"],"unit_price":["150"],"pack_size":["15"],"unit_pack":["1"],"packing":["Pot"],"total_kg":["15"],"total_price":["2250"]}
```

Please tall me where I did wrong.

Note: If you ask why I use Json format? my ans is, I've tried normal ways I knew, but those did not work. So I had to use Json format.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`json_array()` is a function, not a field of a table, therefore you must not use a table prefix when you call it. So, it is simply `JSON_ARRAY("product_id")`.